# Qt : QImage load data from memory

Tags: qt, qimage

I am new to StackOverFlow and wish there are experts to my problem, which consumed me a week time!

I embedded my JPEG files into a single data file, and need to load them on demand to avoid memory problem in mobile phone.

I wrote something like:

```
char *imageBuffer = getBytes(sourceFilename, offset, length);
```

to get a JPEG file data from a sourceFile  with offset and length. I saved the bytes to file and it works.

My problem is how can I construct a QImage from the (char *) data? I tried many methods and haven't any success.

Wishing that there is experienced members to solve my problem. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can load using [`QImage::loadFromData()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#loadFromData).

Comment: Hi Luca, your reply really increased my confidence. In fact I tried the method before and failed many times. After your reply, I reviewed my code throughly and found that I loaded too many images in another routine and so the loadFromData call failed. It was so hard because I can only test the program on a Symbian XpressMusic phone and today only found that if I created more than about 6 QImages from JPEG, it will termainate with no reason!

Comment: Yes, it might fail for memory problems or when format cannot be determined reading the header data. You might want to try to embed using Qt resource file as a double check.